# Download datatable to excel without htmltags in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

In R Shiny, Is there any way to allow user to download the table to excel with rendered format, instead of having html tags in the excel content?

Comment: What do you mean by "rendered format"? Usually, the openxlsx package is useful to generate excel workbooks out of R: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/vignettes/Formatting.html

Comment: The best way to do this is to have your data stored in a reactive before you modify it with HTML tags and then use the same data for your excel download